# EaselJS: update tweens as fast as possible while playing MovieClips at 30 FPS

Tags: createjs, easeljs, adobe-animate

I have **Adobe Animate** project exported to *HTML5* which uses `CreateJS` as a backbone. All animations in AA (in terms of **MovieClip**s) seem to be implemented with 30 FPS in mind.
So, when I have `CreateJS` ticker defined like this:

```js
    createjs.Ticker.framerate = 30;
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener( 'tick', stage )
```

everything plays as expected, though when I add `createjs.Tween`-based movements - those look **very** twitchy.
Tweenings become completely smooth when setting `createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF`, **but** AA exported `MovieClip`s animations, then, become sped up.

Tried this way with no change to `createjs.Tween`, nor AA `MovieClip`s:

```js
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener(
        "tick",
        s => stage.update( s.delta ),
    )
```

Is there a way to separate programmatic tweenings from AA-exported `MovieClip` updates, so that tweenings will become smooth while MovieClip animations update as if it's still 30 FPS?